# Why does echo * behaves as ls and printf * not?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Consider these `shell` commands

```
$ls
my_app  newlist  note
```

and

```
$echo *
my_app  newlist  note
```

and

```
$printf *
my_app
```

The first command `ls` will List information about the files (the current directory by default).
The second command `echo` is a command that outputs the strings it is being passed as arguments. However when I type `echo *` it is outputting the same as `ls`.

And `printf *` only giving me the first filename as output

Why is `echo` interpreting the `*` like this?
And why `printf`, being even stranger: with only outputting the first?

Comment: did you try reading e.g. [the man page for `printf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html)...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Why `echo` interprets the `*` to do the same as `ls`

The answer is simple. It is not. `echo` does exactly as you say: it iterates through its arguments and outputs them with a space between them.

### So why do we see a behaviour like `ls`?

This because the shell will substitute the `*` with a parameter list matching all files (not starting with a `.` (unless dotglob in on)). Then `echo` just does its thing. This glob substitution will happen for **all** commands, as it is done by the shell, not by the command.

### So what about `printf`?

`printf` is print formatting. The first argument is the format. If you do `printf "%s " *`, then it is like `echo`.

If the first file is `hello%sworld`, then you get: `hellofile2world hellofile3world`

### To explore more

Try this. It will help you learn what is happening. (I am not suggesting that you use this code for anything real. Just use it for learning).

Try `cat /proc/self/cmdline * | less` -- It will show at the start, what the command line looks like (after the shell has done its bit).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information.

Comment: Which of my answers was the one?

Comment: the second one and about the printf behaviour. Again Thank you

Comment: @Isaac `PROMPT_COMMAND` has nothing to do with it. `cat` won`t see that on its argument list. And yet this (`cat /proc/self/cmdline *`) is stupid. Don't do it. At least not in any production code. I only suggest doing it as a learning exercise.

Comment: @Isaac Yes. As I said it is not practical. However it does allow us to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

just because it has no input to display but a list of * (all) files as parameter to display as string

as simple as that

while * is parameter it echoes the "*" content so the list of files

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information. And why printf * only giving me the first filename as output?